# 'How To' Linking a Blazor Component to a contact view ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, recaptcha

I followed this online tutorial as I wanted to add ReCaptcha to my contact form and decided to give this a go.

https://elliottbrand.com/blog/1/Creating-a-Contact-Form-in-AspNet-Core-31-MVC-Using-Google-reCAPTCHA-and-Blazor

I followed all the instructions and I have most of the functionality done for the website I am developing, however I am stuck getting the `ContactComponent` to show in the view. I am using the default navigation in an ASP.NET Core application.

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-dark"  asp-area="" asp-controller="Controller" asp-action="Component">Contact</a>   
</li>
```

My problem is that the Contact View will not render the `ContactComponent` locally.

Do I need to inject the Contact Component into the contact View or is it just a linking issue.

Just getting back into my development career so I am sorry if sounds silly as I feel its just a link issue. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> getting the ContactComponent to show in the view

Try to use the [component tag helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/component-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to render Blazor components in cshtml views.

```
 <component type="typeof(Counter)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

Read [Prerender and integrate ASP.NET Core Razor components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerendering-and-integration?view=aspnetcore-3.1&pivots=server#render-components-from-a-page-or-view) to know more.

Comment: Thanks I changed the path of the View and re-started and all is good, just wasn't seeing it!! Thank You!!